# Converting a continuous metric to a proportion for increased power

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, proportion, continuous-data, ab-test

I run online A/B tests and I guess I have some basic stats background, but I've encountered a situation where I don't feel confident about.

We plan to track page load time in each experiment to make sure that our alternative variant doesn't cause a significant drop in the page load time. However, since this metric is a continuous variable with a big variability, in our setting it may be greatly underpowered since we calculate the required sample size based on the main metric which is conversion rate.

I assumed that we may convert the continuous metric to a proportion:

- if the page load time is lower that the industry acceptable threshold of 3 second - we consider it a success
- if the page load time is higher than 3 seconds we consider it a failure.

My reasoning is we should get more power and a greater chance to detect the change in the page load time since and we are not particularly interested in by how much the page speed increases or decreases - we are only interested in whether it changes or not.

Of course the most obvious caveat is we can have a situation where the average page load time increases but the proportion of relatively fast page loads (under 3 seconds) remains the same, but I am actually not sure this is possible.

Is this a valid statistical approach or should I take a different route?

Comment: Ae you sure of what you want?

First, you want to look at whether the load time is over 3 seconds. Then you say you want to look at whether load time changes.  Those are different. 

But also, I find it hard to believe that the 3 second wall is what you want.  A user won't notice a difference between 2,9 and 3.1 seconds, but you are treating those differently.  Users will notice a difference between 0.2 and 2.9 seconds, or between 3.1 and 10 seconds, but you are treating those pairs the same. 

I don't know anything about this field, but that seems wrong.

Comment: when considering page load times, we usually focus on quantile metrics, such as the p99 page load time, as most visits tend to experience very shorter page load time

Comment: To start with why not use Wilcoxon rank sum test so in first instance test that data in the two samples come continuous distributions with equal medians?